# Storing Every Single Inputs and Then Displays In Order

Tags: python, python-3.6

Is there actually a way to store every different input for n number of inputs and then displays all of them all together in correct order for example:

*The User Inputs Record Number, Name, Employee Type, Number Of Days Worked For n number of users*

After n number of users, it displays the following **all at once**:

> Record Number: 1
>
> Employee Name: Alexander
>
> Employee Type: C
>
> Days Worked:5
>
> Pay(RM):2500.00
>
> Record Number: 2
>
> Employee Name: Bella
>
> Employee Type: V
>
> Days Worked:10
>
> Pay(RM):1000.00
>
> Record Number: 3
>
> Employee Name: Tom
>
> Employee Type: S
>
> Days Worked:20
>
> Pay(RM):5000.00

Or is it only possible to display one by one? Here is my current code

```
print("{0:^15s}{1:^25s}".format("Employee Type", "Employee Rate (per day)"))
print("{0:^15s}{1:>15s}".format("C", "RM 500.00"))
print("{0:^15s}{1:>15s}".format("S", "RM 250.00"))
print("{0:^15s}{1:>15s}".format("V", "RM 100.00"))
print()

numEmployee = 1
confirmation = 0

while confirmation != "Y":
    numEmployee = input("Enter The Number Of Employees To Be Keyed In: ")
    while numEmployee == str():
        print("No Input Has Been Detected. Please Input Number Of Employee(s) In An Integer")
        numEmployee = input("Enter The Number Of Employees To Be Keyed In: ")
    while eval(numEmployee) <= 0:
        print("Please Enter A Valid Number Of Employees")
        numEmployee = input("Enter The Number Of Employees To Be Keyed In: ")
    confirmation = input("Are You Sure You The Number Of Employee Is Correct? Enter Y to Continue or any other key to reenter The Correct Number:")
    confirmation = confirmation.upper()
print()

numEmployee = eval(numEmployee)

#for recordNum in range (1, numEmployee + 1):
recordNum = 1
finalTotalC = 0
finalTotalS = 0
finalTotalV = 0

while recordNum <= numEmployee:
    print("Record Number: ", recordNum)
    recordNum = recordNum + 1

    name = input("Employee Name: ")
    while name == str():
        print("Please Enter A Name")
        name = input("Employee Name: ")

    employeeType = input("Employee Type: ")
    employeeType = employeeType.upper()
    while employeeType == str():
        print("No Input Has Been Detected. Please Input An Employee Type")
        employeeType = input("Employee Type: ")
        employeeType = employeeType.upper()
    while employeeType != "C" and  employeeType != "S" and  employeeType != "V":
        print("Employee Type Is Invalid. Please Enter C,S or V Only")
        employeeType = input("Employee Type: ")
        employeeType = employeeType.upper()

    daysWorked = input("Days Worked: ")
    while daysWorked == str():
        print("No Input Has Been Detected. Please Input Number Of Days Worked In That Month")
        daysWorked = input("Days Worked: ")
    while eval(daysWorked) < 0 or eval(daysWorked) > 31:
        print("Please Enter The Number Of Days In A Range Of 0 until 31 Only")
        daysWorked = input("Days Worked: ")

    daysWorked = eval(daysWorked)

    if employeeType == "C":
        EMPLOYEERATE = 500.00
        print("Pay (RM): ", format(daysWorked*EMPLOYEERATE, ",.2f"))
        totalC = daysWorked*EMPLOYEERATE
        finalTotalC = finalTotalC + totalC
        print()

    if employeeType == "S":
        EMPLOYEERATE = 250.00
        print("Pay (RM): ", format(daysWorked*EMPLOYEERATE, ",.2f"))
        totalS = daysWorked*EMPLOYEERATE
        finalTotalS = finalTotalS + totalS
        print()

    if employeeType == "V":
        EMPLOYEERATE = 100.00
        print("Pay (RM): ", format(daysWorked*EMPLOYEERATE, ",.2f"))
        totalV = daysWorked*EMPLOYEERATE
        finalTotalV = finalTotalV + totalV
        print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the data somewhere, as you are receiving it. I would suggest a list (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of dicts (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) might be appropriate for your case. Then you can iterate over the list after you're done (in order to print).